# Is it possible to perform audio processing using AVAudioEngine on the audio being played while screen recording with ScreenCapturekit

Tags: swift, avaudioengine, screencapturekit

My requirement is that, when you start recording using `screencapturekit` framework, I want to perform some modifications on the audio being played and then play the modified audio(say apply `pitch` effect). On stop recording, the audio process must also stop so that the audio must be heard with original sound.

```
func stream(_ stream: SCStream, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, of outputType: SCStreamOutputType) {

    guard sampleBuffer.isValid else { return }
    
    switch outputType {
    case .screen:

    case .audio:
        guard let samples = createPCMBuffer(for: sampleBuffer) else { return }
        movie?.playerNode?.scheduleBuffer(samples)
}
```

This is the code I tried with where I get screen contents and audio separately and then pass the audio to `AVAudioEngine` for processing, but it doesn't work

Comment: In simple The above mentioned code sends the sample buffer that is being captured. But I want to get the sample buffer before being captured, so that I can silence the audio / apply some effect and record it. Is it possible using ScreenCaptureKit. Can someone help me to answer this?